# Match a list of users against /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have a simple one-column list of users. It comes from the lastlog command. I need to be able to tell if these accounts are disabled and I do not have root access. I can only view with more and execute the lastlog command. I need to see if users that havent logged in within the last 90 days are still active.

So far I execute

```
sudo lastlog -b 90
```

Which gives me the users that logged in..in the last 90 days. Now I just run it through awk printing the first field and that is my simple user list. Now Id like to basically see if in /etc/passwd, their shell is /bin/bash and if in /etc/shadow, there is a `!` in their line. How can I do this. I tried for loops and while loops and cant seem to get it right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify what output you're looking to get exactly? That would be helpful when writing a script. Also, can you even read /etc/shadow without root access?

Comment: yes i have access to the more command as root and also grep as root. I think I found what I was looking for using grep -f users /etc/passwd (actually /etc/passwd had to be formatted to grep only /bin/bash out of it since I only want active users from that so I redirected it to another file). So in the end it was `grep -f users bash_users`. Does that sound right?

Comment: see the answer for my approach. hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand you properly. Is that what you are after?

```
lastlog -b 90 | awk '{if (NR > 1) print $1 }' | grep -f - /etc/passwd | grep "/bin/bash$"
```

Here's the breakdown:

- `awk '{if (NR > 1) print $1 }'` - print the first column skipping the first line (lastlog's header)
- `grep -f - /etc/passwd` - use the standard input as a file to obtain patterns from and search for patterns in `/etc/passwd`
- `grep "/bin/bash$"` - grep for /bin/bash , `$` means `EOL`.

A few notes:

- `lastlog -b 90` - that gives you records **older** than 90 days. If you want users that logged in within the last 90 days use `lastlog -t 90`.
- I only went with `(NR > 1)` solution because we're using `awk` anyway. More succinct way of skipping the first line of a file would be `sed 1d`.

**EDIT**

You can use a similar idiom if you also want to filter out the records with `!` from /etc/shadow. So the complete command would be:

```
lastlog -b 90 | awk '{if (NR > 1) print $1 }' | grep -f - /etc/passwd | grep "/bin/bash$" | cut -d ':' -f 1 | grep -f - /etc/shadow | grep -v ":\!:"
```

- `cut -d':' -f 1` splits the line using `:` as a delimiter and returns the first field
- `grep -v` means *invert match* (select non-matching lines).

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation point as you have noticed needs to be 'escaped out' -- try entering searches for it with a backslash first:  \! instead of ! so it doesn't execute it like a command instead of being treated as text. You could also in many cases quote it with single quotes (not double) like so: '!' -- depending on the command you choose one of those should do it for you.